# Inherit node location from User location

Tags: drupal, location

What I want to do is using Drupal 7 and the Location module is to inherit or default the nodes location to the users location. The reason being I just want the user to edit one location (on their profile) and it to show on all nodes created by that user. Can anyone help?

http://drupal.org/node/1357614

http://drupal.org/node/377600

Edit:

I found this module and I'm trying to get the Latitide and Longitude working (as the rest do) but the parent case 'locpick' is confusing the hell out of me and I just cannot get this going.

```
<?php

function location_alter($argument){
$location_alter = array();
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;
$location_alter = user_load($uid);
$location_alter = $location_alter->location;
return $location_alter[$argument];
}

/**
* Implementation of hook_locationapi().
*/
function locnodeauthor_locationapi(&$obj, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL, $a5 = NULL) {
switch ($op) {
 case 'field_expand':
  switch ($a3) {
    case 'name':
      return array(
        '#type'           => 'textfield',
        '#title'          => t('Location name'),
        '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('name'),
        '#size'           => 64,
        '#maxlength'      => 64,
        '#description'    => t('e.g. a place of business, venue, meeting point'),
        '#attributes'     => NULL,
        '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
      );

    case 'street':
      return array(
        '#type'           => 'textfield',
        '#title'          => t('Street'),
        '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('street'),
        '#size'           => 64,
        '#maxlength'      => 64,
        '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
      );

    // Additional is linked to street.
    case 'additional':
      return array(
        '#type'           => 'textfield',
        '#title'          => t('Additional'),
        '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('additional'),
        '#size'           => 64,
        '#maxlength'      => 64,
        // Required is forced OFF because this is technically part of street.
      );

    case 'city':
      return array(
        '#type'           => 'textfield',
        '#title'          => t('City'),
        '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('city'),
        '#size'           => 64,
        '#maxlength'      => 64,
        '#description'    => NULL,
        '#attributes'     => NULL,
        '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
      );

    case 'province':
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'location') .'/location_autocomplete.js');
      $country = $a5['country'] ? $a5['country'] : variable_get('location_default_country', 'us');
      return array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('State/Province'),
        '#autocomplete_path' => 'location/autocomplete/'. $country,
        '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('province'),
        '#size' => 64,
        '#maxlength' => 64,
        '#description' => NULL,
        // Used by province autocompletion js.
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('location_auto_province')),
        '#required' => ($a4 == 2),
      );

    case 'country':
      // Force default.
      if ($a4 == 4) {
        return array(
          '#type' => 'value',
          '#value' => variable_get('location_default_country', 'us'),
        );
      }
      else {
        $options = array_merge(array('' => t('Please select'), 'xx' => 'NOT LISTED'), location_get_iso3166_list());
        return array(
          '#type'           => 'select',
          '#title'          => t('Country'),
          '#default_value'  => $obj,
          '#options'        => $options,
          '#description'    => NULL,
          '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
          // Used by province autocompletion js.
          '#attributes'     => array('class' => array('location_auto_country')),
        );
      }
      break;

    case 'postal_code':
      return array(
        '#type'           => 'textfield',
        '#title'          => t('Postal code'),
        '#default_value'  => $obj != '' ? $obj : location_alter('postal_code'),//$location_alter['postal_code'],//location_alter('postal_code'),
        '#size'           => 16,
        '#maxlength'      => 16,
        '#required'       => ($a4 == 2),
      );
  }
  break;


case 'isunchanged':
  switch ($a3) {
    case 'lid':
      // Consider 0, NULL, and FALSE to be equivilent.
      if (empty($obj[$a3]) && empty($a4)) {
        return TRUE;
      }
      break;

    case 'country':
      // Consider '  ' and '' to be equivilent, due to us storing country
      // as char(2) in the database.
      if (trim($obj[$a3]) == trim($a4)) {
        return TRUE;
      }
      break;

    case 'province_name':
    case 'country_name':
    case 'map_link':
    case 'coords':
      // Always considered unchanged.
      return TRUE;
  }
  break;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you intend to use the results of this, you may not even need to save the location of a node. I.e., if you want to access the Location data in Views, you can use a relationship to access the Location data of a node's author even though the Location data may not be saved on the node at all. However, doing this would mean that your nodes in views will always be associated with their authors' current locations, not the locations they had set when they created the nodes.

If you do want to save this on the node, you'll need to create a custom module. You'll probably want to call [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to hide the Location field on the node edit form, and [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to copy the user's Location value over to the node's Location value.